# Checkbox PHP AJAX

Tags: checkbox, ajax, php

Ребята, кто подскажет как сделать такую штуку: мне нужно при выборе чекбокса из базы вытягивать инфу, соответствующую value выбранного чекбокса.. вот с селектом я разобрался

```
<form id="myForm">
Выберите Категорию:<br/>
<select id="idcat">
<?php
//Выводим категории и ее ID
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
print "<option value=".$row['id'].">";
print $row['name'];
echo("</option>");
}
?>
</select>
</form>
<div id="content"></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#idcat').change(function(){
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "handler.php",
data: "idcat="+$("#idcat").val(),
success: function(html){
$("#content").html(html);
}
});
return false;
});

});
```

Дальше идет handler.php

```
<?php
include "../blocks/db.php"; //Подключаем БД
//делаем запрос на товары этой категории
$reqid = $_REQUEST['idcat'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM goodies WHERE manufacturer='$reqid'");
// выводим товары полученные по запросу
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
print $row['title']."<br>";
}
?>
```

Так вопрос в том, как сделать тоже самое для чекбоксов (когда выбираешь 1 - выводятся все тайтлы соответствующие этому элементу, когда убераешь, то выводятся все тайтлы вообще, а если 2, то по порядку..) Два дня сижу уже, икак не могу додуматься..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#idcat').change(function(){
```

функция отправки данных срабатывает когда вы выбираете какое-либо значение из вашего выпадающего списка.

Чтобы отправить данные на сервер вам нужно событие на клик по чекбоксу, я `change` сделал, но можно и `click`:

html.

```
<input type="checkbox" value="test" name="myCheck" />
```

javascript:jQuery.

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){

    // Проверка стоит галочка или нет
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {

        var chk = $(this).attr("name");
        var chkVal = $(this).attr("value");

        // Ваш запрос
        $.ajax({
            url: 'test.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: { name: chk, val: chkVal },
            beforeSend: function() { alert(chk+ ' '+chkVal); },
            success: function(data) { alert(data); }
        });

    }

});
```

Comment: Ответ хорошо, но я нашел "баг", сейчас при изменении состояния чекбокса выводится инфа, следовательно, если у меня стояла галочка, я ее убираю - и все равно показывается инфа соответствующая value, потому что был выбран чекбокс и убрали, значит состояние изменилось - показывает еще раз.. а так быть не должно =(

Comment: я обновил ответ